# Parse string with two sets of delimiters and inconsistent spacing and create a flat associative array

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array, text-parsing, delimited

I need to explode by "," then ":".

```
$alttitle = "35:title1,36:title2, 59:title5"
$replacetitles = explode(",",$alttitle);
for ($i = 0 ; $i < count($replacetitles) ; $i++) {
   $replacetitle[] = explode(":", $replacetitles[$i]);
}
```

Which produces...

```
Array (
  [0] => Array (
    [0] => 35
    [1] => title1
  )
  [1] => Array (
    [0] => 36
    [1] => title2
  )
  [2] => Array (
    [0] => 59
    [1] => title5
  )
)
```

...but the number 35,36,59 are unique so I want this to become the key for the array.

```
Array (
  [35] => title1
  [36] => title2
  [59] => title5
)
```

Comment: Is this a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/526556/how-to-flatten-a-multi-dimensional-array-to-simple-one-in-php?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply set it while looping:

```
$alttitle = "35:title1,36:title2, 59:title5"
$tmptitles = explode(",",$alttitle);

$replacetitle = array();
foreach($tmptitles as $tmptitle) {
   $tmparr = explode(":", trim($tmptitle));
   $replacetitle[intval($tmparr[0])] = trim($tmparr[1]);
}
```

With the above, you will create your array a minimum number of iterations.

Comment: if you add a `trim` to `$tmparr[0]`, this will be the IMHO most elegant solution.

Comment: heh, sorry there seems to be a lag where I am. How do I split more than 1 correct answer?! :)

Comment: **@EddyR:** You can't. Chose the one that suits you best, which would be usually the community chose.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my take

```
$alttitle  = "35:title1,36:title2, 59:title5";

$entries   = preg_split( "/ *, */", $alttitle );
$flattened = array();

for ( $i = 0, $l = count( $entries ); $i < $l; $i++)
{
  list( $index, $value ) = explode( ':', $entries[$i] );
  $flattened[$index] = $value;
}

print_r( $flattened );
```

### EDIT

Now with speed test vs explode/trim

```
$testData = implode( ',', array_fill( 1, 10000, "a,b, c,  d" ) );

$start = microtime( true );
$entries = explode( ",", $testData );
$ouptput = array();

for ( $i = 0, $l = count( $entries ); $i < $l; $i++ )
{
  $output[] = trim( $entries[$i] );
}
echo "explode/trim test took: ", ( microtime( true ) - $start ), ' seconds<br>';

unset( $start, $entries, $output );

$start = microtime( true );
$entries = preg_split( "/ *, */", $testData );
$ouptput = array();

for ( $i = 0, $l = count( $entries ); $i < $l; $i++ )
{
  $output[] = $entries[$i];
}
echo "preg_split test took: ", ( microtime( true ) - $start ), ' seconds<br>';
```

Comment: preg_split is much less performant than explode followed by trim.

Comment: Are you sure about that?  Try the test I posted above.

Comment: **@Peter Bailey:** Your code fails to handle input such as `32:My Nice Book, 57:The Terror Of The Seas, 92: Hello World`

Comment: **@Peter Bailey:** And in the interest of keeping the result the same as using `trim`, you should use `preg_split( "/\s*,\s*/m", $alttitle );`

Comment: Well, technically speaking if I wanted to 100% mimic trim(), it would need to be `"/[\\s\\r\\n\\0\\x0B]*,[\\s\\r\\n\\0\\x0B]*/"` but I'll leave such minutiae as an exercise for EddyR

Comment: On my machine (WinXP, Core2Duo) explode+trim needs about .04 seconds and preg_split needs .047 seconds with your test. Small, but significant.

Comment: Significant? *Really?* .007 seconds on 10,000 iterations when the likely sample data set is going to be far less?  I think you worry too much about premature optimizations.  P.S. with multiple runs, the preg_split test ran an average of 60% faster, although in some test runs the explode/trim test was faster, which for me even further highlights why niggling over this sort of thing is academic at best.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another but probably overkill alternative.

```
if (!preg_match_all('/([0-9]+)\s*:\s*([^,]+)/', $alttitle, $matches)) {
    //not valid   
}

$array = array_combine($matches[1], $matches[2]);
print_r($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify the process by exploding only once, then call `sscanf()` inside if the loop.  `%d` will cast the numeric value as an integer and eliminate the worry regarding whitespaces.

- a special mention: `%s` will stop matching when it encounters a white space. If this is a concern, use a negated character class or change the function to `explode()` with a limit parameter of `2`.

Code: [(Demo)](https://3v4l.org/YfoR4)

```
$alttitle = "35:title1,36:title2, 59:title5";

foreach (explode(',',  $alttitle) as $pair) {
    [$id, $result[$id]] = sscanf($pair, '%d:%s');
}
var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
array (
  35 => 'title1',
  36 => 'title2',
  59 => 'title5',
)
```

Answer (score -2):

After your code you can add this:

```
$ar = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < count($replacetitle); $i++) {
    $ar[$replacetitle[$i][0]] = $replacetitle[$i][1];
}
```

Comment: it is generally better to be in the habit of not using count (or other functions) on a fixed value in a loop expression. for ($i = 0, $t = count($replacetitle); $i < $t; $i++) {

Comment: This one is probably one of the least efficient solution. Your adding a another loop to create something you should of done first.