# Jquery, using "inarray" on a nested array to find a specific value's index?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, search

I'm struggling with this, I am still new to javascript and am trying the jquery $.inarray function as I need to be able to find a value in an array so that I can return other values from the same array "line", such as its ID.

When I try to use jquery's inarray function, like this, I just get back -1, saying that it doesn't exist when I know the value exists, nested within the array.. I'm not sure of how to approach this so that I can search for a value, any advice is greatly appreciated.

```
valuereturn = $.inArray("search_for_value", jsonarray) ;
alert (valuereturn)
```

EDIT 2:

Here is the result of my echo'ing the JSON from cakephp:

```
    {"getdata":[{"Uiemail":{"uiemail_id":"2","divid":"upd1","width":"200","height":"200","leftpos":"122","toppos":"122","cssgroup":"1","colortop":"","colorbottom":"","colorborder":"","borderwidth":"","zindex":""}},
{"Uiemail":{"uiemail_id":"3","divid":"upd2","width":"200","height":"200","leftpos":"333","toppos":"444","cssgroup":"1","colortop":"","colorbottom":"","colorborder":"","borderwidth":"","zindex":""}},
{"Uiemail":{"uiemail_id":"4","divid":"upd3","width":"200","height":"200","leftpos":"555","toppos":"466","cssgroup":"1","colortop":"","colorbottom":"","colorborder":"","borderwidth":"","zindex":""}}]}
```

EDIT:

Also, here is the output of:

```
alert(typeof jsonarray+'\n'+jsonarray.length)
output= "object 3 "
```

I tried this also, but it doesn't give a value and makes errors on my page:

```
alert(jsonararray)
```

Comment: Could we a see a sample of your JSON output?

Comment: I'm a javascript newbie.. I can't figure out how to get the actual JSON output.. its being generated by cakephp.. any advice on how to go about this? I am searching on show json output but nothing of use is coming up.. thanks for your help in this

Comment: can you post
alert(typeof jsonarray+'\n'+jsonarray.length+'\n'+jsonararray);

Comment: Thanks.. I updated the post with the info the last one, alert(jsonarray) doesn't work

Comment: @Rick: If the JSON data is coming from CakePHP output, can you not navigate to the page directly and see the output?

Comment: Yes :), I figured out how to do it, just by echoing it in a normal way rather than the way it was doing to send it to javascript.. I edited the OP above

Comment: What's an example, given the test data above, of the kind of "value in an array" that you'd be searching for?

Comment: well, the purpose behind this is so that, for any value, I can find its ID (for the purpose of this example, lets say "divid") so that when I send the data back to the server I can update based on using this id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still not completely sure what you're asking, so here are some assumptions and a quickie solution.

9. You're looking for `uiemail_id`s in that blob of data
10. The blob could be arbitrarily deep
11. If you find one, you want to get the value of the `divid` in the same "line"
12. First one found is the winner

Now throw together a little recursive function:

```
function deepsearch ( blob, val ) { 
    var result = false;
    for( var item in blob ) {
        if( typeof blob[item] === 'object' ) {
            result = deepsearch( blob[item], val );
            if( result != false ) return result;
        } else if( blob[item] == val && item == 'uiemail_id' ) {
            // found item, blob = obj in which found
            result = blob.divid; // the divid from this "line"
            break; // assume first found wins            
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Plopping in your exact JSON:

```
var arr = {"getdata":[{"Uiemail":...
```

We can now look for a `uiemail_id` of `4`, and get the corresponding `divid` of `upd3`:

```
deepsearch( arr, '4'); // returns upd3
deepsearch( arr, '3'); // returns upd2
```

This is probably brittle, and certainly can be improved, but maybe it gives you an angle of attack.

Comment: Thanks for the info.. I just gave up on this actually by just pre-breaking down the arrays into "normal" arrays on the PHP side then sending them over to javascript

Answer (score 0):

Well, for now I've decided to use an approach of flattening the arrays within javascript and pre-processing the data that way since I can't figure out how to do it in javascript.. I found this:

[How to "flatten" a multi-dimensional array to simple one in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/526556/how-to-flatten-a-multi-dimensional-array-to-simple-one-in-php)

This should enable me to move on past this issue but I am interested if anyone knows how to accomplish what I am trying to do directly in javascript (search within the nested array)