# PHP merge array(s) and delete double values

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

WP outputs an array:

```
$therapie = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Therapieen', false);
print_r($therapie);

//the output of print_r
Array ( [0] => Massagetherapie ) 
Array ( [0] => Hot stone )
Array ( [0] => Massagetherapie )
```

**How would I merge these arrays to one and delete all the exact double names?**

Resulting in something like this:

```
theArray
(
[0] => Massagetherapie 
[1] => Hot stone
)
```

[SOLVED] the problem was if you do this in a while loop it wont work here my solution, ty for all reply's and good code.: Its run the loop and pushes every outcome in a array.

```
<?php query_posts('post_type=therapeut');
$therapeAr = array(); ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<?php $therapie = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Therapieen', true);
if (strpos($therapie,',') !== false) { //check for , if so make array
$arr = explode(',', $therapie);
array_push($therapeAr, $arr);                       
} else {
array_push($therapeAr, $therapie);
} ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php           
function array_values_recursive($ary)  { //2 to 1 dim array
$lst = array();
foreach( array_keys($ary) as $k ) {

$v = $ary[$k];
if (is_scalar($v)) {

$lst[] = $v;
} elseif (is_array($v)) {

$lst = array_merge($lst,array_values_recursive($v));

}}
return $lst;
}

function trim_value(&$value) //trims whitespace begin&end array
{ 
$value = trim($value); 
}

$therapeAr = array_values_recursive($therapeAr);
array_walk($therapeAr, 'trim_value');
$therapeAr = array_unique($therapeAr);  

foreach($therapeAr as $thera) {
echo '<li><input type="checkbox" value="'.$thera.'">'.$thera.'</input></li>';
} ?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following should do the trick.

```
$flattened = array_unique(call_user_func_array('array_merge', $therapie));
```

or the more efficient alternative *(thanks to [erisco](https://stackoverflow.com/users/260584/erisco)'s comment)*:

```
$flattened = array_keys(array_flip(
    call_user_func_array('array_merge', $therapie)
));
```

If `$therapie`'s keys are strings you can drop `array_unique`.

Alternatively, if you want to avoid `call_user_func_array`, you can look into the various different ways of flattening a multi-dimensional array. Here are a few ([one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/526556/how-to-flatten-a-multi-dimensional-array-to-simple-one-in-php), [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319903/how-to-flatten-a-multidimensional-array)) good questions already on SO detailing several different methods on doing so.

I should also note that this will only work if `$therapie` is only ever a 2 dimensional array **unless** you don't want to flatten it completely. If `$therapie` is more than 2 dimensions and you want to flatten it into 1 dimension, take a look at the questions I linked above.

Relevant doc entries:

[`array_flip`](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php)
[`array_keys`](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php)
[`array_merge`](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)
[`array_unique`](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php)
[`call_user_func_array`](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php)

Comment: Advice that Gumbo gave me: `array_unique()` and `array_keys(array_flip())` both accomplish the same thing, except they have time complexities of `O(nlogn)` and `O(n)` respectively.

Comment: ty, This code probably would work, but sadly I can't get it to work. I guess it has something to do with the variable  $therapie holding 3 different arrays. For the record I've tried all of the code examples above.

Comment: @Rob edit your answer to include _(using the above method)_, a `print_r` of `$therapie` before and after, and the __EXACT__ code you're running it through.

Comment: sorry, small update in the hurry i've coped it wrong, is right now.

Comment: @Rob It's kind of hard to tell what's going on without knowing what all those functions are doing. My best guess is that `$therapie` is `NULL` or an empty string. Try `var_dump`ing `$therapie` instead.

Comment: I've solved it, it was because I was running all the code in a while loop... see op

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like the keys of the arrays you are generating are insignificant. If that's the case, you can do a simple [merge](http://php.net/array_merge) then determine the [unique](http://php.net/array_unique) ones with built in PHP functions:

```
$array = array_merge($array1, $array2, $array3);
$unique = array_unique($array);
```

**edit:** an example:

```
// Emulate the result of your get_post_meta() call.
$therapie = array(
  array('Massagetherapie'),
  array('Hot stone'),
  array('Massagetherapie'),
);

$array = array();

foreach($therapie as $thera) {
  $array = array_merge($array, $thera);
}

$unique = array_unique($array);

print_r($unique);
```

Comment: ty, array_merge($therapie); gives me the same output I'd like to merge. Also $therapie gets loaded with dynamic values that differ. Can I merge all of the $therapie arrays without specifying them?

Comment: @Rob my answer should be what you're looking for.

Comment: You can't merge the output straight away. Think about what your output gives you (i.e. an array of arrays). You're on the right path in terms of looping through them, you just need to build an array of all the values present (and I recommend using array_merge in that), and then find out any unique values (thus the array_unique).

Comment: Could you please give an example of that (code)? I think I understand what you mean and the code you're giving. If I'm right the variable $therapie holds 3 arrays with different integers,  But I can't get it to work merging them...

Comment: Thank you. I've tried to run the code, but I didn't get any output from the print_r. Don't know what's going on. Could it be the wp loop is causing problems? I posted the complete code in the op.

Answer (score 2):

PHP's [array_unique()](http://php.net/array-unique) will remove duplicate values from an array.

Answer (score 0):

```
$tester = array();
foreach($therapie as $thera) {
   array_push($tester, $thera);
}
$result = array_unique($tester);
print_r($result);
```