# Merging data in "type array" elements in an array, together in a new array

Tags: php

I think I blew you away by the title. But here's what I exactly need:

I have an array like this:

```
array(
 '0' => array( 'the','data','i'),
 '1' => array( 'need', 'is', 'this'),
 '2' => array( 'complete', 'sentence')
);
```

which I want to become:

```
array(
 'the','data','i','need','is','this','complete','sentence'
);
```

What's random:

1. The number of elements in a child array element.
2. The number of child array elements.

Comment: Probable dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/526556/how-to-flatten-a-multi-dimensional-array-to-simple-one-in-php

Comment: The solution there, would it good to process over 10k elements(total)?

Comment: Good question, @KPL.  The solutions there do consider the general case in which the arrays are nested to an arbitrary depth. If you are interested only in merging at the top level, then you can write something more efficient without using recursion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the problem you posed does not appear to be the general one of recursive flattening, it is probably worth giving the simple solution as an answer here, even though other SO questions address the general case.

All you need is

```
call_user_func_array("array_merge", $a);
```

To see it in a complete script:

```
<?php
$a = array(
    array( 'the',' data', 'i' ),
    array( 'need', 'is', 'this' ),
    array( 'complete', 'sentence' )
);

echo var_dump($a);
echo "<br/><br/><br/>";
$b = call_user_func_array("array_merge", $a);
echo var_dump($b);
?>
```

This builds up the result by appending arrays and can be inefficient.  You can check out `SplFixedArray` which allows you to preallocate space.  Then traverse the constituent arrays in your original array and load up the result.  Here is a blog post that discusses `SplFixedArray` and includes timing results: http://www.johnciacia.com/2011/02/01/array-vs-splfixedarray/

Here is a verbose version:

```
<?php
$a = array(
    array( 'the','data','i'),
    array( 'need', 'is', 'this'),
    array( 'complete', 'sentence')
);

$size = 0;
foreach ($a as $subarray) {
    $size += count($subarray);
}

$result = new SplFixedArray($size);
# If you do not have SPL, just use $result = Array(); and write to a high index first (probably)

$i = 0;
foreach ($a as $subarray) {
    foreach ($subarray as $value) {
        $result[$i++] = $value;
    }
}

echo var_dump($result);
?>
```

Comment: But, does `array_values` not serve the same purpose?

Comment: The [`array_values`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) function just produces a numerically indexed array, ignoring keys.  I don't see how it helps for flattening, but that doesn't mean it cannot be used.