# PHP: Many arrays into one

Tags: php, arrays

I am doing a small calculator, that has randomly selected sequence of 3 chars (`-`, `/` and `\`).

How can I combine my three arrays into one? I'm using `array_merge`, but it creates an array that nests 3 arrays in it. How can I make this array one-dimensional?

My code (feedback welcome):

```
$_SESSION["sekvenssi"] = 15; //sekvenssi means "sequence" in Finnish.

$maara1 = rand(1, $sekvenssi/2);  //Maara means "amount"
$maara2 = rand(1, $sekvenssi/2);

$kenot = array_fill(0, $maara1, "/");
$vastakenot = array_fill(count($kenot), $maara2, "\\");
$tayte = array_fill(
    count($kenot)+count($vastakenot),
    $_SESSION["sekvenssi"]-$maara1-$maara2,
    "-"
);

$kaava = array_merge(array($tayte), array($kenot), array($vastakenot));
shuffle($kaava);

print "<p style='font-family: Courier;font-size: 18px;'>";
    foreach ($kaava as $komponentit) {
    print $komponentit;
}
print "</p>";
```

So this outputs "ArrayArrayArray", but I want it to produce one array with only one level (now it has 2 levels and thus cannot be printed).

Comment: Well, one "best practice" would be not to post code to an English-speaking forum where there are non-English variable names. :)

Comment: @BenLee I'd argue it's slightly different, as he seems to have a handfull of differences such as assumptions he can't print a 2-d array, he's merging three arrays rather than flattening one, etc...

Comment: Sorry about that, next time I'll do better :)

Comment: In the meantime people have already given answers, so I won't repeat what they've said, but for the record the term you were looking for is "flatten the array". See for example [question 526556](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/526556/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have already created the array's when you use array_fill, so when you merge them, you are then creating another set of arrays with each array.

Try changing this:

```
$kaava = array_merge(array($tayte), array($kenot), array($vastakenot));
```

to

```
$kaava = array_merge($tayte, $kenot, $vastakenot);
```

Comment: Thank you alot! That did it! I just love this community, I got an answer in about 3 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
$kaava = array_merge(array($tayte), array($kenot), array($vastakenot));
```

to

```
$kaava = array_merge($tayte, $kenot, $vastakenot);
```

you can use print_r() or var_dump() to test-output variables in php. it will even correctly display arrays and objects.