# Create an array of inner array values with array function in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to “flatten” a multi-dimensional array to simple one in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/526556/how-to-flatten-a-multi-dimensional-array-to-simple-one-in-php)

How to create an array of inner array values with array function ?

Here is array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [Detail] => Array
        (
            [detail_id] => 1
        )

    )

    [1] => Array
    (
        [Detail] => Array
        (
            [detail_id] => 4
        )

    )

)
```

I want create an array with `detail_id` of above array  i.e

```
array(1, 4)
```

Is it done any array function in PHP ?

Comment: i think all the array functions can be useful for 1-D array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am looking for answer like this

```
$result = array_map( function($a) {
    return $a['Detail']['detail_id']; }, $mainArray
);
```

This works correct..

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any one function which can do this single-handed.  `array_map` is the closest you'd get, but it doesn't really deal with the extra recursion level.  Why don't you just use loops?

```
$new_array = array();

foreach($main_array as $key => $second_array)
{
   foreach($second_array as $second_key => $third_array)
   {
      $new_array[] = $third_array['detail_id'];
   }
}

echo implode(',',$new_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

If your are looking for a one liner:

```
$val = array(
   array('Detail' => array('detail_id' => 1)),
   array('Detail' => array('detail_id' => 4)),
 );

var_dump($val);
```