# How can I efficiently get a sub array to be the main array without a foreach loop?

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array, foreach

Here's my array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [same_key] => 1000
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [same_key] => 1001
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [same_key] => 1002
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [same_key] => 1003
        )
)
```

I'd like to get the following without using a foreach loop.  Is this possible?

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1000
    [1] => 1001
    [2] => 1002
    [3] => 1003
)
```

Any tips?

Comment: foreach loop is a good way .... why not foreach ??

Comment: It's been a while but I thought there were some array functions to do this without the expense of a loop.

Comment: Check out this [answer][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/526556/how-to-flatten-a-multi-dimensional-array-to-simple-one-in-php

maybe it will help you even more

Comment: O yes. Sorry about the delayed acceptance of your answer.  Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following will do the trick

```
$myArray = Array
(
    0 => Array
        (
            'adfadf'=> 1000
        ),
    1 => Array
        (
            'adfadf' => 1001
        ),
    2 => Array
        (
            'adfadf' => 1002
        ),
    3 => Array
        (
            'adfadf' => 1003
        )
);

$myArray = array_map('current', $myArray));
```

Answer (score 2):

you can do this by `$array = array_map('current', $array);`

[live example](http://codepad.org/EoaAxRUA)

output

[image]

Comment: That code won't work in his case. array_map('current', $array[0]) will only return the first element in his array which for this case would be 1000.