# how to work with arrays

Tags: php, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to “flatten” a multi-dimensional array to simple one in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/526556/how-to-flatten-a-multi-dimensional-array-to-simple-one-in-php)

how do i turn

```
Array  
(  
    [0] => Array 
  (
      [id] => 33          
      [name] => Robb's Event  
  )  
)
```

into this

```
Array  
(  
   [id] => 33             
   [name] => Robb's Event  
)
```

Comment: For a 2D array with only one element, `$array = array_pop($array)`

Answer (score 9):

```
$array = $array[0];
```

Please learn some basics on [arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)!

Comment: +1 for a simple and straightforward answer!

Comment: @str what if the array is having multiple arrays??

Comment: @YogeshSuthar Apparently that was not required, and if it was, we do not know in what form it should have transformed the array.