# How to convert two dimensional array to one dimensional array in php?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am Having an mutidimensional array getting result like given below

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 70
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 67
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 75
            [1] => 73
            [2] => 68
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 68
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 76
        )

)
```

But I need to convert it to single array

And I want to convert in to single dimensional array as

```
Array
(
[0] => 70
[1] => 67
[2] => 75
[3] => 73
[4] => 68
[5] => 68
[6] => 76
)
```

How to convert it using php functions?

Or Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to "flatten" a multi-dimensional array to simple one in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/526556/how-to-flatten-a-multi-dimensional-array-to-simple-one-in-php)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can try

```
$it =  new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($data));
$l = iterator_to_array($it, false);

var_dump($l); // one Dimensional
```

Comment: And Also we Can Add  sort($l); $l = array_unique($l); for removing duplicate elements and for proper indexing for new array

Answer (score 2):

Try with:

```
$input  = array(/* your array*/);
$output = array();

foreach ( $input as $data ) {
  $output = array_merge($output, $data);
}
```

Comment: Just use `$final` instead of `$input`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array_walk_recursive()` for that coupled with a closure:

```
$res = array(); // initialize result

// apply closure to all items in $data
array_walk_recursive($data, function($item) use (&$res) {
    // flatten the array
    $res[] = $item;
});

print_r($res); // print one-dimensional array
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick

```
$final = array();
foreach ($outer as $inner) {
  $final = array_merge($final, $inner);
}
var_dump($final);
```

Or you could use [`array_reduce()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) if you have `PHP >= 5.3`

```
$final = array_reduce($outer, function($_, $inner){
  return $_ = array_merge((array)$_, $inner);
});
var_dump($final);
```

Answer (score 0):

For a more generic function which can deal with multidimensional arrays, check this function,

```
function  arrayFlattener($input = array(), &$output = array()) {
  foreach($input as $value) {
    if(is_array($value)) {
        arrayFlattener($value, $output);
    } else {
        $output[] = $value;
    }
  }
}
```

You can find an  example [here](http://codepad.viper-7.com/NSOiqi).

Answer (score 0):

By using this function you can convert any dimension array into a single dimention array.

```
$result = array();
$data = mearchIntoarray($result,$array);
function mearchIntoarray($result,$now)
{
    global $result;
    foreach($now as $key=>$val)
    {
        if(is_array($val))
        {
            mearchIntoarray($result,$val);
        }
        else
        {
            $result[] = $val;
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Where $array is your given array value.