# PHP multidimensional array - foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have a problem getting array values "lat" and "long" without going deeper by foreach function. Array:

```
array(1) {
  ["Berlin, Germany(All airports)"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["Berlin Brandenburg Willy Brandt(BER)"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["lat"]=>
      string(9) "52.366667"
      ["lon"]=>
      string(9) "13.503333"
    }
  }
```

}

Function:

```
foreach($results as $key => $val){  
  //here i want to reach lat and long without additional foreach loop
}
```

Thank you all for answers.

Comment: You might want to use: [array_walk_recursive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/526556/how-to-flatten-a-multi-dimensional-array-to-simple-one-in-php)

Comment: Note that BER isn't going to be opened for a while ;-) Sad story.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
foreach($results as $key => $val){  
  $temp = current($val); # fetch first value, which is array in your example
  echo $temp['lat'];
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$val = current($val)`, or `$temp['lat']`?

Comment: @Supericy, mistake, i fixed.

Comment: I deliberately created $temp variable, so you can still use $val. But if you don't need it anymore, then of course, overwrite it.