# Create a flat array of values from an array column containing array-type data

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, flatten, array-column

I have this array in PHP.

```
$all = array(
array(
    'titulo' => 'Nome 1',
    'itens' => array( 'item1', 'item2', 'item3')
),
array(
    'titulo' => 'Nome 2',
    'itens' => array( 'item4', 'item5', 'item6')
),
array(
    'titulo' => 'Nome 4',
    'itens' => array( 'item7', 'item8', 'item9')
));
```

I need to merge specific child arrays. In other words, I need to get the `itens` column of data (which contains array-type data) as a flat result array like this:

```
$filteredArray = array('item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4', 'item5', 'item6', 'item7', 'item8', 'item9');
```

I can do this using `foreach()`, but are there any other more elegant methods?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I want to add sub arrays to one single array in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14951811/i-want-to-add-sub-arrays-to-one-single-array-in-php)

Comment: @ishegg that duplicate is not appropriate for this question because the OP doesn't want to flatten the entire contents of the input array, just one column of data.  This is an important distinction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reduce the `itens` column of your array, using `array_merge` as the callback.

```
$filteredArray = array_reduce(array_column($all, 'itens'), 'array_merge', []);
```

Or even better, eliminate the `array_reduce` by using the ["splat" operator](http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php#migration56.new-features.splat) to unpack the column directly into `array_merge`.

```
$result = array_merge(...array_column($all, 'itens'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a loop and array_merge:

```
$filteredArray = array();
foreach ($all as $array) {
   $filteredArray = array_merge($filteredArray, $array['itens']);
}
print_r($filteredArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through your arrays and join them:

```
$filteredArray = array();

foreach($all as $items) {
    foreach($items["itens"] as $item) {
        array_push($filteredArray, $item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function array_flatten($array) {
  if (!is_array($array)) {
    return false;
  }
  $result = array();
  foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if (is_array($value)) {
      $result = array_merge($result, array_flatten($value));
    } else {
      $result[$key] = $value;
    }
  }
  return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another unmentioned technique is to iterate the input array and push a variable number of elements into the output array.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/isC0s))

```
$result = [];
foreach ($all as $row) {
    array_push($result, ...$row['itens']);
}
var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'item1',
  1 => 'item2',
  2 => 'item3',
  3 => 'item4',
  4 => 'item5',
  5 => 'item6',
  6 => 'item7',
  7 => 'item8',
  8 => 'item9',
)
```