# php turn this array into integer series

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, keyvaluepair

this is the output of my array

`[["1"],["1"],["1"],["1"],["1"],["1"],["1"],["1"],["1"],["1"],["1"],["1"],["1"],["1"]]`

but I would like this to look like

`[1,1,1,1,1,1,1]`

how would this be achieved in php, it seems everything I do gets put into an object in the array, when I don't want that. I tried using array_values and it succeeded in returning the values only, since I did have keys originally, but this is still not the completely desired outcome

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/526556/how-to-flatten-a-multi-dimensional-array-to-simple-one-in-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$yourArray = [["1"],["1"],["1"],["1"],["1"],["1"],["1"],["1"],["1"],["1"],["1"],["1"],["1"],["1"]];
```

use following code in `PHP 5.3+`

```
$newArray = array_map(function($v) {
    return (int)$v[0];
}, $yourArray);
```

OR use following code in other PHP version

```
function covertArray($v) {
    return (int)$v[0];
}

$newArray = array_map('covertArray', $yourArray)
```

Comment: I can't do anonymous functions, using php 5.2 because the server is using that

Comment: I change it to naming function.

Answer (score 0):

You could always do a simple loop...

```
$newArray = array();

// Assuming $myArray contains your multidimensional array
foreach($myArray as $value)
{
   $newArray[] = $value[0];
}
```

You could beef it up a little and avoid bad indexes by doing:

```
   if( isset($value[0]) ) {
      $newArray[] = $value[0];
   }
```

Or just use one of the many array functions to get the value such as `array_pop()`, `array_slice()`, `end()`, etc.