# PHP multidimensional array key collapse

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, httprequest, multipartform-data

I'd like to collapse a multidimensional array so that

```
$arr = array(
    'first' => array(
        'second' => array(
            0 => 'foo',
            1 => 'bar'
        )
    )
);
```

would collapse to

```
$arr = array(
    'first[second][0]' => 'foo',
    'first[second][1]' => 'bar'
);
```

What I'm trying to do is to restore a `multipart/form-data` `$_POST` array to the original request body, like this:

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryxiOccKlMg4Al6VbH
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="first[second][0]"

foo
------WebKitFormBoundaryxiOccKlMg4Al6VbH
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="first[second][1]"

bar
------WebKitFormBoundaryxiOccKlMg4Al6VbH--
```

Comment: Extend the example, by this example your question is vague! Also put your works and what you have done so far.

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/526556/how-to-flatten-a-multi-dimensional-array-to-simple-one-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
$arr = array(
    'first' => array(
        'second' => array(
            0 => 'foo',
            1 => 'bar'
        )
    )
);
$result = array();
function processLevel(&$result, $source, $previous_key = null) {
    foreach ($source as $k => $value) {
        $key = $previous_key ? "{$previous_key}[{$k}]" : $k;
        if (!is_array($value)) {
            $result[$key] = $value;
        } else {
            processLevel($result, $value, $key);
        }
    }
}
processLevel($result, $arr);
var_dump($result);
die();
```

It outputs:

```
array(2) {
  ["first[second][0]"] => string(3) "foo"
  ["first[second][1]"] => string(3) "bar"

}
```

Comment: please use more self-explaining variable names, so that we can easier know what's happening ;-)

Comment: I tried to write it as fast as possible to be the first who posts the answer)

Comment: Then change it now, you aren't prohibited from editing... (and yeah, you were the first, my answer was a 6-7 seconds later^^)

Comment: obfuscated code would look worse :-P I still understand what's happening, but it isn't suitable for copypasting for example...

Comment: Very impressive @BogdanBurim, it's exactly what I was trying to achieve, simple and concise!

Answer (score 0):

```
function collapseArray ($array, $tree = array(), $step = 0) {
    $result = array();
    foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
        $tree[$step] = $key;
        if (is_scalar($val)) {
            $first = array_shift($tree);
            $result["{$first}[".implode("][", $tree)."]"] = $val;
            array_unshift($tree, $first);
        } else {
            $result += collapseArray($val, $tree, $step + 1);
        }
    }
    return $result;
}

$arr = array(
    'first' => array(
        'second' => array(
            0 => 'foo',
            1 => 'bar'
        )
    )
);

$newArray = collapseArray($arr);
```

Outputs when var_dump()'ed:

```
array(2) {
  ["first[second][0]"]=>
  string(3) "foo"
  ["first[second][1]"]=>
  string(3) "bar"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

what about this?

```
$arr = array(
    'first' => array(
        'second' => array(
            0 => 'foo',
            1 => 'bar'
        )
    )
);
$newArray=array();
foreach($arr['first']['second'] as $k=>$v)
{
    $newArray['first[second]['.$k.']']=$v;
}

var_dump($arr);
var_dump($newArray);
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: @BogdanBurim: any words about universal solution in question?

Comment: It is obvious that it should be universal, also it is obvious that the array he provided is sample.

Comment: By the way hello from Kharkiv.

Comment: @BogdanBurim: it is not mentioned that array can contain many keys on `first` or `second` level. Seems that only level with integer keys can be adjusted

Comment: @BogdanBurim: hello from Kharkiv :)