# Convert nested array into single array using php

Tags: php, arrays

i having a nested output like this

$arr = array();

$arr = array (size=2)

```
0 => 
  array (size=2) 
     0 => string '28' (length=2) 
     1 => string '7973' (length=4) 
1 => 
  array (size=1) 
     0 => string '4595' (length=4)
```

my expected output like this

$new_array = array

```
0 => 28
1 => 7973
2 => 4595
```

Pls help me to solve this...

advance thanks....

Comment: [What have you tried so far?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: have you tried merging them at the source (we do not see your code) or using array_merge?

Comment: thats is single array with nested array.. not 2 dimensional array.. thanks

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/526556/how-to-flatten-a-multi-dimensional-array-to-simple-one-in-php

Answer (score 2):

This is just as simple as doing an array_merge:

```
array_merge($arr[0], $arr[1]);
```

[PHP - array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/PY1Yye)

Comment: Inside your nested array, there are arrays. You are just merging both of them. See the demo.