# PHP5 - Remove indexes from the array

Tags: php, arrays

I have array like this:

```
array(2) {
    [0]=> array(1) { 
        ["name"]=> string(8) "TestName" 
    } 
    [1]=> array(1) { 
        ["surname"]=> string(6) "iljado" 
    } 
}
```

and I need it to be like this:

```
array(2) { 
    ["name"]=> string(8) "TestName" ,
    ["surname"]=> string(6) "iljado" 
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Can you edit the code that generate the array?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to "flatten" a multi-dimensional array to simple one in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/526556/how-to-flatten-a-multi-dimensional-array-to-simple-one-in-php)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/526556/how-to-flatten-a-multi-dimensional-array-to-simple-one-in-php/14972714#14972714

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Recursively merge them:

```
$array = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $array);
```