# Multidimensional array to array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, array-map

I have an array like this

```
$category = [
'cat1' => [
    'images/category/cat1/icon1.jpg',
    'images/category/cat1/icon2.jpg',
    'images/category/cat1/icon3.jpg',
],
'cat2' => [
    'images/category/cat2/icon1.jpg',
    'images/category/cat2/icon2.jpg',
    'images/category/cat2/icon3.jpg',
]
];
```

I want to get the array like this

```
$categories = [
'images/category/cat1/icon1.jpg',
'images/category/cat1/icon2.jpg',
'images/category/cat1/icon3.jpg',
'images/category/cat2/icon1.jpg',
'images/category/cat2/icon2.jpg',
'images/category/cat2/icon3.jpg',
];
```

I tried this but not got expected output.

```
$categories = array_map(function($cat){return $cat;},$category);
```

Comment: You're more likely to get help if you post the actual output you received.  (But thanks for showing us what output you want and what you tried.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to "flatten" a multi-dimensional array to simple one in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/526556/how-to-flatten-a-multi-dimensional-array-to-simple-one-in-php)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/526556/how-to-flatten-a-multi-dimensional-array-to-simple-one-in-php/14972714#14972714

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `call_user_func_array` in conjuction with `array_merge`:

```
$category = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $category);
```

Answer (score 1):

Can be solve by `array_reduce()` & `array_merge()`

```
$categories = array_reduce($category, function($old, $new){
    return array_merge($old, $new);
}, array());
```