# angularjs orderBy not working right

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, angularjs

```
I have an array with this form

$vars[1][1]["name"]     = "John";
$vars[1][1]["lastname"] = "Doe";
$vars[1][2]["name"]     = "Ely";
$vars[1][2]["lastname"] = "Tim";


$vars[2][1]["name"]     = "Brad";
$vars[2][1]["lastname"] = "Vinnie";
$vars[2][2]["name"]     = "Angelina";
$vars[2][2]["lastname"] = "Van";

.....

$vars[10][1]["name"]     = "Ela";
$vars[10][1]["lastname"] = "Pearl";
$vars[10][2]["name"]     = "Gustavo";
$vars[10][2]["lastname"] = "Tim";

which is in PHP. After that I send it to angularJS and i have

$scope.varArr = data.vars
```

after that in view I have

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, det) in varArr| orderBy: key">
     {{det.name}} {{det.lastname}}
 </div>
```

The problem is that it's not taking the array in the order 1,2,3...10

It's taking $vars[1] after that $vars[10] and after that $vars[2]. Instead of making the order after the number it's making after the string.

This situation is only if I have $vars[1][1] and $vars[1][2]...etc

If I would have only $vars[1][1], $vars[2][1], .... $vars[10][1] it will take the order after the number.

Answer (score 0):

In the [Angular doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#iterating-over-object-properties), it says that when you use the `(key, value)` method:

> You need to be aware that the JavaScript specification does not define
>   the order of keys returned for an object. (To mitigate this in Angular
>   1.3 the ngRepeat directive used to sort the keys alphabetically.)
>
> Version 1.4 removed the alphabetic sorting. We now rely on the order
>   returned by the browser when running for key in myObj. It seems that
>   browsers generally follow the strategy of providing keys in the order
>   in which they were defined, although there are exceptions when keys
>   are deleted and reinstated. See
>   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete#Cross-browser_issues
>
> If this is not desired, the recommended workaround is to convert your
>   object into an array that is sorted into the order that you prefer
>   before providing it to ngRepeat. You could do this with a filter such
>   as toArrayFilter or implement a $watch on the object yourself.

One way to handle this is to flatten the array into a single dimension before passing it to the document. [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/526556/how-to-flatten-a-multi-dimensional-array-to-simple-one-in-php) has several answers on how to "flatten" a multidimensional array in PHP.

Comment: I've changed the AngularJS version from 1.3 to 1.4 and now it's working, but I've put <div ng-repeat="(key, matchdet) in allMatches | orderBy: 'key': reverse">  and it's not making the order descending

Answer (score 0):

Apostrophes missing:

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, det) in varArr| orderBy: 'key'">
```

without apostrophes Angular is looking for function 'key' in your controller, which does not exist neither