# Array map, flatten, and unset on a single multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, array-map

I've got a multidimensional array of the format:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [course_prefix] => AERO
        [0] => AERO
        [course_number] => 101
        [1] => 101
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [course_prefix] => AERO
        [0] => AERO
        [course_number] => 102
        [1] => 102
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [course_prefix] => AERO
        [0] => AERO
        [course_number] => 201
        [1] => 201
    )
)
```

And I'm attempting to perform three operations:

1. unset all elements with the [0] and [1] keys,
2. Combine the [course_prefix] and [course_number] values in each subarray,
3. Flatten to a single array

So that the end result is

```
Array
(

"AERO 101",

"AERO 102",

"AERO 201"

)
```

I understand that `array_map` can combine two different arrays, and that `unset` removes elements, but how can I perform the operations when everything is in the same multidimensional array - e.g. unsetting elements not at top level, and combining values?

Comment: Start by modifying your database fetch to return only an associative array, not both

Comment: Why don't you just not create the `0`, `1` keys in the first place? It looks like this is coming from a database query. If you use `fetch_assoc` instead of `fetch_array`, it will just return the named indexes.

Comment: You can also use the db query to combine the two columns for you as well, so you won't need to do it in PHP

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to "flatten" a multi-dimensional array to simple one in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/526556/how-to-flatten-a-multi-dimensional-array-to-simple-one-in-php)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback; I'm actually very new to SQL and did not realize it was possible to concatenate columns inside a query (I also didn't realize PDO returns two versions of a DB's data in its response), so between revising my query and only fetching the associative array I've accomplished everything without processing the result in PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a simple `array_map`:

```
$new_array = array_map(function($row) {
    return $row['course_prefix'] . ' ' . $row['course_number'];
}, $array);
```