# Finding string in array

Tags: php, arrays

Alright, so I'm querying the DB and generating an array from a list of IP addresses:

```
$q = 'SELECT ip FROM proxy';
$r = mysqli_fetch_all($con->query($q), MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

Array returned looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ip] => 1.202.244.222
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [ip] => 1.226.238.136
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [ip] => 1.228.231.247
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [ip] => 1.238.106.137
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [ip] => 1.238.155.191
        )
```

But if I want to find say the first or any IP in the above list, for some reason it doesn't find anything:

```
$ip = "1.202.244.222";
if(in_array($ip,$r)) {       
echo "gotcha";       
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: It's an array of an array... Collapse the thing, and then it'll work. There are a couple of options here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/526556/how-to-flatten-a-multi-dimensional-array-to-simple-one-in-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an array of arrays... Collapse the thing, and then it'll work. There are a couple of options here: [How to "flatten" a multi-dimensional array to simple one in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/526556/how-to-flatten-a-multi-dimensional-array-to-simple-one-in-php)

Answer (score 2):

Got confused by the array within array stuff which I didn't notice at first.
Thanks to Zeth's pointers, I got it to work by collapsing the arrays into one by adding:

```
$r0 = array_column($r, 'ip');
```

And then:

```
if(in_array($ip,$r0)) {       
echo "gotcha";       
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The most flexible approach for such situations is to use a user defined comparison function:

```
<?php
$needle = '1.202.244.222';
$haystack = [
    [
        'ip' => '1.202.244.222'
    ],
    [
        'ip' => '1.226.238.136'
    ],
    [
        'ip' => '1.228.231.247'
    ],
    [
        'ip' => '1.238.106.137'
    ],
    [
        'ip' => '1.238.155.191'
    ]
];

$result = array_filter($haystack, function($entry) use ($needle) {
    return isset($entry['ip']) && $needle === $entry['ip'];
});
print_r($result);
```

The output of above code obviously is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ip] => 1.202.244.222
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Array condition was wrong.

```
   $ip_find = '1.202.244.222';
$ip_values = [
    [
        'ip' => '1.202.244.222'
    ],
    [
        'ip' => '1.226.238.136'
    ],
    [
        'ip' => '1.228.231.247'
    ],
    [
        'ip' => '1.238.106.137'
    ],
    [
        'ip' => '1.238.155.191'
    ]
];

foreach ($ip_values as $key => $value) {
foreach ($value as $key => $ip) {
if ($ip==$ip_find) {
    echo $ip."  Gocha";
    break;
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using foreach:

```
$r = [
    [
        'ip' => '1.202.244.222'
    ],
    [
        'ip' => '1.226.238.136'
    ],
    [
        'ip' => '1.228.231.247'
    ],
    [
        'ip' => '1.238.106.137'
    ],
    [
        'ip' => '1.238.155.191'
    ]
];

$ip = "1.202.244.222";

foreach($r as $elem)
{
    if($elem['ip'] == $ip)
    {    
        echo "gotcha";
        break;
    }
}
```