# how to make single array using all index value?

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
Array
(
    [8] => Array
        (
            [9] => Array
                (
                    [13] => Array()
            )
    )

[14] => Array
    (
        [15] => Array()
    )
)
```

I want all index value in single array like this one `array('8','9','13','14','15');`

Comment: Array ( [8] => Array ( [9] => Array ( [13] => Array ( )) )
[14] => Array([15] => Array() ))

Comment: You could do an recursive iteration through the array and collect all the keys!?

Comment: you can use `call_user_func_array("array_merge", $input);` where `$input` is INPUT_ARRAY

Comment: Does not work for me @SNTiwari

Comment: what is error ?

Comment: There is no error, just the output is wrong: `Array ( [0] => Array (  [13] => Array ( ) )    [1] => Array ( ) )`

Comment: just search flatten multi dimensional array, https://stackoverflow.com/a/1824445/3859027 on the example just use the key

Answer (score 3):

You could combine the [array_keys](http://php.net/array_keys)() function with recursion to grab all keys inside your array like shown below:

```
// Your given array
$array = [
    8 => [
        9 => [
            13 => []
        ]
    ],

    14 => [
        15 => []
    ]
];

// What this function does, is it loops through the array, and if the given
// value is an array too, it does the same until it hits a value which is not an array
function array_keys_recursive($array, $keys = []) {
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        $keys[] = $key;

        if (is_array($value)) {
            $keys = array_merge($keys, array_keys_recursive($value));
        }
    }

    return $keys;
}

// You call it like a so:
$keys = array_keys_recursive($array);
print_r($keys); // Outputs Array ( [0] => 8 [1] => 9 [2] => 13 [3] => 14  [4] => 15 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one possible way to do this. I've use recursion.

```
<?php


function getkeys($arr) {
    $keys = array();
    foreach (array_keys($arr) as $key) {
        $keys[] = $key;
        if (is_array($arr[$key])) {
            $keys = array_merge($keys, getkeys($arr[$key]));
        }
    }
    return $keys;
}


$arr = array(
    8 => array(
        9 => array(
            13 => array()
        )
    ),
    14 => array(
        15 => array()
    )
);


print_r(getKeys($arr));
```