# Looping and combine multiple array to one

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array looks like this:

```
 Array
     (
        [0] => Array
               (
                  [name] => color
                  [value] => red
               )

        [1] => Array
               (
                  [name] => shape
                  [value] => square
               )

        [2] => Array
              (
                  [name] => price
                  [value] => $15
              )
     )
```

I want to have a result like this:

```
    $myArr = array (
        'color' => 'red', 
        'shape' => 'square',
        'price' => '$15'
    )
```

I have tried to loop but can not get it to work.

```
foreach($myArr as $id => $values){
    foreach ($values as $key => $value) {
        if($key == 'name') {
            //add to array key
        } else {
            //add to that array key value 
        }
    }
 }
```

hope you guys can help me with solution.

Comment: really, this has been here a million times already

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to "flatten" a multi-dimensional array to simple one in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/526556/how-to-flatten-a-multi-dimensional-array-to-simple-one-in-php)

Comment: Thanks guys, I actually knew it's very basic but don't know what term to search for the right answer, my search result is always something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `array_column` and `array_combine`

```
$arr = array(
    array("name" => 'color',"value" => 'red'),
    array("name" => 'shape',"value" => 'square'),
    array("name" => 'price',"value" => '$15')
);

$newArr = array_combine(array_column($arr,'name'),array_column($arr,'value'));

echo "<pre>";
print_r( $newArr );
echo "</pre>";
```

This will result to:

```
Array
(
    [color] => red
    [shape] => square
    [price] => $15
)
```

Doc: [array_column](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php), [array_combine](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php)

Comment: Happy to help @pexichdu

Answer (score 1):

```
$a = [
    0 => [
        "name" => "color",
        "value" => "red",
    ],
    1 => [
        "name" => "shape",
        "value" => "square",
    ],
    2 => [
        "name" => "price",
        "value" => "$15",
    ]
];

$b = [];

foreach($a as $v)
{
    $b[$v["name"]] = $v["value"];
}

var_dump($b);
```

result

```
array(3) {
  ["color"]=>
  string(3) "red"
  ["shape"]=>
  string(6) "square"
  ["price"]=>
  string(3) "$15"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr = array
     (
        0 => array
               (
                  'name' => 'color',
                  'value' => 'red'
               ),

        1 => array
               (
                  'name' => 'shape',
                  'value' => 'square'
               ),

        2 => array
              (
                  'name' => 'price',
                  'value' => '$15'
              )
);
$final_array =[];

foreach($arr as $key=> $val){
    $final_array[$val['name']] = $val['value'];
    }
echo "<pre>"; print_r($final_array);
```