# Reduce not work correctly i need add exeption / exlusion

Tags: php, arrays, array-merge, array-reduce

i have an array like that in $_POST var; but need know that in some cases the array is a hugge multilevel from json:

```
array (
  'idprocess' => 'f-gen-dato1',
  'idform' => 'f-gen-dato2',
)
```

OR:

```
array (
  array (
    'idprocess1' => 'f-gen-dato1',
    'idform1' => 'f-gen-dato2',
  ),
  array (
    'idprocess2' => 'f-gen-dato1',
    'idform2' => 'f-gen-dato2',
  )
)
```

i try to reduce; any arrays with this:

```
public function ReduARR($Var) {
        $result = $Var;
        if (is_array($Var)) {
            $result = array_reduce($Var, 'array_merge', array());
        }
        return $result;
    }
```

but i need avoid the array i show you... frist or single level. and work only in the second or multilevel.

i get this error with one lvl:

```
array_merge(): Argument #2 is not an array
```

Comment: Maybe this would help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14972714/6487675

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you wish to merge or reduce some arrays, and you might be trying to write some functions similar to:

```
$arr1 = array(
    'idprocess1' => 'f-gen-dato1',
    'idform1' => 'f-gen-dato2',
);

$arr2 = array(
    'idprocess2' => 'f-gen-dato1',
    'idform2' => 'f-gen-dato2',
);

function finalArray($arr1, $arr2)
{
    if (is_array($arr1) && is_array($arr2)) {
        return mergeTwoArrays($arr1, $arr2);
    }
}

function mergeTwoArrays($arr1, $arr2)
{
    return array_merge($arr1, $arr2);
}

var_dump(finalArray($arr1, $arr2));
```

for instance.

---

```
$arr = array(
    array(
        'idprocess1' => 'f-gen-dato1',
        'idform1' => 'f-gen-dato2',
    ),
    array(
        'idprocess2' => 'f-gen-dato1',
        'idform2' => 'f-gen-dato2',
    ),
);

if (is_array($arr[0]) && is_array($arr[1])) {
    var_dump(array_merge($arr[0], $arr[1]));
}
```

#### Output

```
array(4) {
  ["idprocess1"]=>
  string(11) "f-gen-dato1"
  ["idform1"]=>
  string(11) "f-gen-dato2"
  ["idprocess2"]=>
  string(11) "f-gen-dato1"
  ["idform2"]=>
  string(11) "f-gen-dato2"
}
```

Comment: really the variable array that I want to reduce is that of $ _POST

Comment: nope i need reduce array ... becouse index 0 and 1 not wort... you can see the example... of the script and the error...

Comment: is the same as your ouput but in single lvl array i get error, i need avoid it