# How to format different level of array in same array to get only values?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I am trying to get an array of only values, from an array having different dimensions:

My output array is in the form below

```
array[
    0 => 1
    1 => array[
    0 => 6
    1 => array[
     0 => 7
     1 => 8
    ]
  ]
]
```

My required array is in form:-

```
 array(1, 6, 7, 8)
```

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/526556/how-to-flatten-a-multi-dimensional-array-to-simple-one-in-php

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to "flatten" a multi-dimensional array to simple one in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/526556/how-to-flatten-a-multi-dimensional-array-to-simple-one-in-php)

Comment: Thank as lot @VincentDecaux, I solve my issue from your provided link.

Answer (score 0):

[How to Flatten a Multidimensional Array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319903/how-to-flatten-a-multidimensional-array)

You can use the Standard PHP Library (SPL) to "hide" the recursion.

```
$a = array(1,2,array(3,4, array(5,6,7), 8), 9);
$it = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($a));
foreach($it as $v) {
  echo $v, " ";
}
```