# What is the best approach to create an array having specific key's value from a multidimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Hello i have an multidimensional array
each of the array contains key of `"id_category"`

I am trying to store value of key `"id_category"` while loop through the multidimensional array.

**Here is the array & php compiler**

**https://paiza.io/projects/H8FwXLAZc438-XA-hnmNHQ?language=php**

```
$save_id_category = [];
foreach($array as $ct){
    $save_id_category[] = $ct['id_category'];
}
print_r($save_id_category); // this gets me only one record.
```

I can loop through all array & save data but that would be not good idea.

Please let me know if we have a better approach
for this.
Thanks

Comment: You probably want [`array_column`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column)

Comment: I had used = print_r(array_column($children, 'id_category'));
but gives only one record

Comment: Please do check the array data here -  https://paiza.io/projects/H8FwXLAZc438-XA-hnmNHQ?language=php

Comment: Please use `var_export` instead of `print_r` for your sample data, then it can be used directly in PHP.

Comment: Updated array, Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a recursive function to find all the `id_category` values, first getting all the values at the current level using [`array_column`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column), then iterating over the children of each array element to add their categories to the list:

```
function get_categories($array) {
    $categories = array_column($array, 'id_category');
    foreach ($array as $ct) {
        $categories = array_merge($categories, get_categories($ct['children'] ?? array()));
    }
    return $categories;
}

print_r(get_categories($arrayone));
```

Output (for your sample data):

```
Array
(
    [0] => 12
    [1] => 13
    [2] => 15
    [3] => 16
    [4] => 48
    [5] => 68
    [6] => 58
    [7] => 282
    [8] => 17
    [9] => 18
    [10] => 85
    [11] => 52
    [12] => 53
    [13] => 86
    [14] => 54
    [15] => 55
    [16] => 56
    [17] => 217
    [18] => 275
    [19] => 69
    [20] => 70
    [21] => 71
    [22] => 278
    [23] => 59
    [24] => 60
    [25] => 61
    [26] => 283
)
```

Comment: I am generating the "arrayone" from here $arrayone = Category::getNestedCategories(19, 1); Is their any way we can loop through the arrayone function and change argument i.e "19" ?

Comment: @newphpdev I'm not sure what you mean? perhaps something like `$categories = [1, 5, 12];
foreach ($categories as $category) {
    $arrayone = Category::getNestedCategories($category, 1);
}`?

Comment: I am trying to form a single array by merging two array keys into one

Comment: This - Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 5
              
            )
        [1] => Array
            (
                [id] => 8
               
            )
    )

Comment: To This - Array ( [0]  => 5 ) ( [1] => 8 )

Comment: `array_column($array, 'id')` will do what you want

Comment: Hello, please take a look at this https://paiza.io/projects/G-nyByVA-rg5kwS1bcHJ0g?language=php

Comment: @newphpdev lots of ideas on how to flatten an array [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/526556/how-to-flatten-a-multi-dimensional-array-to-simple-one-in-php)