# Foreach is display Array text instead of showing the actual values within an array

Tags: php, loops, foreach

So I've been pulling my hair trying to figure out why the output is showing an `Array` text instead of displaying the actual values. Below is an array that I'm trying to fetch the values.

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(6) "400 ml"
    [1]=>
    string(2) "1L"
    [2]=>
    string(2) "2L"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(8) {
    [0]=>
    string(17) "100% Orange Juice"
    [1]=>
    string(5) "Apple"
    [2]=>
    string(4) "Pear"
    [3]=>
    string(9) "Pineapple"
    [4]=>
    string(12) "Passionfruit"
    [5]=>
    string(15) "Red Dragonfruit"
    [6]=>
    string(13) "Baobab Powder"
    [7]=>
    string(17) "Grapeseed Extract"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "Yes"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "Yes"
  }
}
```

---

If I tried looping through it using `foreach` it gives me the output `Array Array Array Array`

```
foreach($singleArray as $key => $val) {
    echo $val; 
}
```

---

If I tried specifying the index like below, it gives me the actual values

```
foreach($singleArray[0] as $key => $val) {
    echo $val; 
}
```

Comment: That's because in your first loop `$val` is an array, and when you `echo` an array you get `Array`. You can replace `echo $val` with `print_r($val)` (or `var_dump`, or `var_export`) or you can use a nested foreach loop `foreach($singleArray as $val) { foreach ($val as $v) { echo $v; }}`

Comment: So basically I should do another `foreach`?

Comment: yes, that would be the simplest, as I described in the comment

Comment: My objective is actually fetch all the values in the array and store it in a single array

Comment: That sounds like you want to flatten the array. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319903/how-to-flatten-a-multidimensional-array and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/526556/how-to-flatten-a-multi-dimensional-array-to-simple-one-in-php