# Need to convert array of index array to single dimension index array in php

Tags: php

I need to convert array of index array to single dimension array.

```
$a=[];
$a[0]=[1,2,3];
$a[1]=[4,5,6];
$a[2]=[7,8,9];
$a[3]=[1,4,7];
```

I need to merge these arrays as single array. Is there any built in function available for this? The expected output is

```
 [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,4,7]
```

That output must be an single dimension index array

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Flatten a Multidimensional Array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319903/how-to-flatten-a-multidimensional-array)

Comment: yes partially solved

Answer (score 0):

You can simple use foreach like:

```
$a=[];
$a[0]=[1,2,3];
$a[1]=[4,5,6];
$a[2]=[7,8,9];
$a[3]=[1,4,7];

$b = [];
foreach($a as $array){
    foreach($array as $value){
        $b[] = $value;
    }
}
print_r($b);
```

Result:

> Array (
> [0] => 1
> [1] => 2
> [2] => 3
> [3] => 4
> [4] => 5
> [5] => 6
> [6] => 7
> [7] => 8
> [8] => 9
> [9] => 1
> [10] => 4
> [11] => 7 )

---

Suggest from @catcon you can use `array_merge` like:

```
$new_array = array_merge(...$a)
```

Reference:

- [array_merge](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)

Comment: Im checking is there any alternate solution rather than looping

Comment: Without have a specific key i think is not possible

Comment: `$new_array = array_merge(...$a)` will work in your case

Comment: Yes it'a true. nice solution

Comment: spread operator only work in php 7.4 or higher im using php 7.2

Comment: So you must use `foreach`, and please upgrade your PHP :)

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct solution refereed from [How to Flatten a Multidimensional Array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319903/how-to-flatten-a-multidimensional-array)

```
$a=[];
$a[0]=[1,2,3];
$a[1]=[4,5,6];
$a[2]=[7,8,9];
$a[3]=[1,4,7];
$it = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($a));
$output=iterator_to_array($it, FALSE);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = array_merge(...$a);
print_r($result);
```

The easiest way

Answer (score 0):

From this question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/526556/how-to-flatten-a-multi-dimensional-array-to-simple-one-in-php/15939539):

```
<?php
$a=[];
$a[0]=[1,2,3];
$a[1]=[4,5,6];
$a[2]=[7,8,9];
$a[3]=[1,4,7];

$result = [];
array_walk_recursive($a,function($val) use (&$result){ $result[] = $val; });
var_dump($result);
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/KEHPB#v7.2.34)