# convert array of arrays into comma separated list with unique values - PHP

Tags: php

I have an array that looks like below:

```
$var[] =   ^ array:4 [▼
      0 => array:1 [▼
        0 => "apple"
      ]
      1 => array:1 [▼
        0 => "apple"
        1 => "grape"
      ]
      2 => array:1 [▼
        0 => "orange"
      ]
      3 => array:1 [▼
        0 => "banana"
      ]
    ]
```

Is there a way to convert this array into comma separated list with unique values as below?

```
$var = "apple,grape,orange,banana"
```

I tried implode(', ',$var) but it's not working as expected. Any help pls?

Update: My sub-array may have more than 1 element. It's dynamic.

Comment: Please provide a real PHP code. But [array_unique](https://www.php.net/array_unique) / [array_column](https://www.php.net/array_column) should help.

Comment: Do your inner arrays always have just one element?

Comment: No. My inner array will have one or more elements

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This produces the results given the expected input. Basically `array_column` get's the first item from each item of the array (0 based). Then `array_unique` on that will simply get the values without duplicates.

```php
$arr = [
    ['apple'],
    ['apple'],
    ['banana'],
    ['pie'],
];

print_r(array_unique(array_column($arr, 0)));
```

EDIT: since there might be more than one item in the inner arrays, there's no shame in doing a non one-liner solution:

```
$result = [];
foreach ($arr as $row) {
    foreach ($row as $item) {
        if (array_search($item, $result) === false) {
            $result[] = $item;
        }
    }
}
print_r($result);
```

Comment: Thanks. But in some cases, my inner element has more than 1 element like:$arr = [
    ['apple'],
    ['apple','orange'],
    ['banana'],
    ['pie'],
]; In that case how to change array_column to include all array elements?

Comment: I have edited the question to add a sample. Pls chec

Answer (score 0):

There's also a one-liner solution:

```
$result= array_unique(call_user_func_array('array_merge', $arr));
```

cf. https://stackoverflow.com/a/14972714/13720553